# Using Mysqli prepared statements for currency / money values

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've taken over a project and since the previous developer was using Mysqli, I've stuck with it. I have switched to using prepared statements though.

I was wondering what the best approach is for handling currency values from the user. When binding the variable as a double, it works fine when the input is something like **5.99**, which is expected. But we're talking about input from a user here, so I can imagine cases where they input **$5.99** or **100,000** (using a dollar sign or a comma). With the binding alone, the stored values end up being **0.00** and **100.00** respectively. The column type is decimal(10,2) in the database.

There are probably a few different ways to approach this, such as preventing the user from keying in those characters or doing validation from the frontend, or maybe some other form of data sanitation on the backend. But I wanted to get an idea of what others would do for this case. I can't leave it as it is because I know someone will overlook the fact that the value is not what they originally entered.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dont do it MySQL side, Your application should be able to work out what the user meant. I would suggest

http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php

If its critical, I would also suggest storing as a varchar the original string input by the user for verification / bug fixing later on.

```
$fmt_cur = numfmt_create( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );

$amounts = array("$5.99", "100,000");
foreach ($amounts as $a) {
  ($b = numfmt_parse_currency($fmt_cur, $a, $curr)) ||
  ($b = numfmt_parse($fmt, $a));

  var_dump( $b );

}
```

Returns

```
double(5.99)
double(100000)
```